# Accessible AJAX page transitions for SPA

Tags: ajax, accessibility

I have been tasked with building a SPA that has some complex page transitions.

My biggest concern is that these transitions rely on elements expanding on the page to then become the full page (i.e. you click a blue button, the blue background expands to fill the whole page and then the content is displayed.)

Now this is where I am struggling to come up with an accessible solution. I thought about making the text within the original 'button' a link with padding (as the URL will update and the link is for no JavaScript fallback) and then replacing the content of the parent div (the blue background) with the new content.

The problem I have is that I am not sure what would be the best practice for accessibility from the perspective of letting a screen reader user know that a new page has loaded in. Using `aria-live` is a terrible idea, but with NVDA if I just replace the contents of the div it can have some strange behaviour.

Has anyone ever come across this before? For example [this dribble nearly shows what I mean](https://dribbble.com/shots/7127725-Chummy-UI-Kit-III), you click an element and then it opens up into a new page with the content within the element.

For a 'normal' AJAX site when navigating I would simply replace the whole `<main>` with the new content, make the `<h1>` programatically focused with a `tabindex="-1"`, update the page `<title>` and that works fine, but with this type of navigation I am wondering if the same approach is applicable.

I am thinking replacing everything within the `<main>` element except for the selected 'button' background (including the original link being removed once the new page has loaded) and then loading the content in and managing the focus as described would work, but I am not sure if there is an accepted pattern for this type of navigation as it is so unusual.

Comment: I'm intrigued by your process here. You mentioned programatically setting focus as an accessibility technique, however, in my testing (using NVDA+FF), I set `tabindex="-1"` and set focus using `element.focus()`, but I'm not able to get the screen reader to re-announce any updated sections. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should announce the page `<h1>` and then work like a normal page (i.e. you decide what to interact with). You also need to change the `<title>` and update the URL using the history API for this technique to work.

Comment: In case you haven't read it yet, check out this excellent report on SPAs and what to announce when they re-render: 
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-07-11-user-testing-accessible-client-routing/

Comment: thanks @brennanyoung, they advocate the way i was doing things in a normal application so that's always good to know, however this unusual use case isn't covered so I am still looking for some ideas here, if you have seen any accessible applications using this pattern it would be a massive help!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I wish I had that holy grail! React and other SPA frameworks are monstrously popular, and the fact that any decent solution seems to rely on the presence of hyperlinks or bogus focus targets at the top of the page, suggest that this is just not properly thought-out. My main takeaway from that article is the user citation “no one is doing this well.” - which further suggests to me that it's a shortcoming in ARIA.

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking replacing everything within the  element except
>   for the selected 'button' background (including the original link
>   being removed once the new page has loaded) and then loading the
>   content in and managing the focus as described would work, but I am
>   not sure if there is an accepted pattern for this type of navigation
>   as it is so unusual

I think this is your best best. The whole visual expanding thing is just eye candy, so as long as it is there you should be able to do this behind the scenes. Make sure you test with screen readers.